# Cross stack reference in CDK using Java

Tags: java, aws-cdk

I have created a InfraStack which creates all the required infrastructure resources like VPC, SG, ALB, ASG etc.

Now I have to create another stack say ECSStack, where it creates the ecs tasks, services inside the resources which was created earlier.

So how to pass the one stack resources into another stack using Java CDK. Please let me know if anybody has a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the resources you need as arguments to the stack where you want to use them. AWS CDK will automatically create the required exports.

```java
public class VpcConfigurationStack extends Stack {

    private final Vpc vpc;

    public VpcConfigurationStack(@Nullable Construct scope) {
        super(scope, "vpc-configuration-stack");

        this.vpc = Vpc.Builder.create(this, "Vpc")
                .maxAzs(2)
                .subnetConfiguration(List.of(
                        SubnetConfiguration.builder()
                                .name("Public")
                                .subnetType(SubnetType.PUBLIC)
                                .build()
                ))
                .build();
    }

    public Vpc getVpc() {
        return vpc;
    }

}
```

```java
public class EcsStack extends Stack {

    
    public EcsStack(@Nullable Construct scope, VpcConfigurationStack vpcConfigurationStack) {
        super(scope, "ecs-stack");
       
        Vpc vpc = vpcConfigurationStack.getVpc();
        ...
    }
    
}
```

Please note that this work by means of exports and imports, so the usual rules are applied. For instance, while you're able to define stacks with circular dependencies in Java, such configuration will fail during deployment as CloudFormation doesn't know how to handle these cases.